# Получить значения, которые есть во всех массивах

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 7 массивов вида

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];
$array4 = [];
...
```

Как можно получить массив, содержащий те `value` исходных массивов, которые встречаются в каждом из них? В примере выше есть пустой массив, значит результат тоже будет пустой.

```
$result = [];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];

$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];

var_dump(array_intersect($array1, $array2, $array3));
```

Результат:

```
array(1) {
    [0] => int(1)
}
```