# Поиск одинаковых значений в неопределённом количестве массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть необходимость из нескольких массивов получить значения, которые есть во всех этих массивах. Например

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];
$array4 = [];
```

Результат - пустой массив. Если бы не было последнего массива `$array4`,то результатом поиска была бы 1, т.к. она есть во все массивах.

[Как выяснилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892586/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85), быстро и удобно решить задачу можно c помощью `array_intersect()`. Однако есть большая проблема - я точно не знаю, сколько массивов нужно сравнивать. Их может быть от 0 до 7.

Для меня важно найти схождения только объявленных массивов. Если же массив не был создан, то его не нужно включать.

Например

```
$a = rand(true, false);
$b = rand(true, false);
if ($a) {
    $array1 = [1,3,5,7];
}
if ($b) {
    $array2 = [];
}
$array3 = [1,8,99];
```

В итоге иногда есть пустой массив `arr2`, а иногда его нет. Если этот массив будет объявлен, то результат поиска значения, которое есть во все массивах - пустой массив. Если массив `arr2` не будет объявлен, то результат будет уже другой - 1.

Я могу получить массив объявленных массивов вот так:

```
$all = [
    $array1 ?? null,
    $array2 ?? null,
    $array3 ?? null,
];

foreach ($all as $key => $item) {
    if ($item === null) {
        unset($all[$key]);
    }
}
```

В итоге у меня есть массив с массивами, среди значений которых нужно найти такие значения, которые присутствуют в каждом из этих массивов. Но как это можно сделать?

Comment: Бред но рабочий =) использовать eval =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вам и тут отвечу:  используйте `call_user_func_array` или `...` (начиная с php5.6):

```
array_intersect(...$all);   // c php5.6

call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $all);  // до php5.6
```